# jquery location.reload(true) how to prevent warning message in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a piece of jquery that calls a method on the controller. This method updates items pertaining to what is on the screen.

In order to update the screen I therefore go:

```
location.reload(true);
```

The problem is this is bringing up the message:

"To display this page, Firefox must send information that will repeat any action (such as a search or order confirmation) that was performed earlier."

Could someone please tell me how to prevent this message or an alternative to what I'm doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's happening because you have a form element with a POST action. Most modern browsers will not refresh the page when it was generated as a result of a POST request without asking first - because POST requests could be anything, like deleting a record, or submitting user information. When you access a page simply by going to the Url, that's a GET request.

For this reason it's recommended that you return "RedirectToAction" results from your actions, where state has been changed on a postback - this way, users can hit F5 on the destination page all they like without the error, at the small expense of an extra roundtrip to the server.

Answer (score 3):

The browser gives this warning before refresh a POST page, because POST requests should not be arbitrarily repeated.

You need to do a [POST/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

If you *want* to re-issue the POST, you should explicitly re-POST by submitting a `<form>`.